# quasi-solvable ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, nonlinear-system, hypergeometric-function, singular-solution

I face with a quasi-solvable ode

$x^{2}(1+x^{2})y''+2xy'+A(1+x^{2})^{2}y=0$

where $A$ is a constant. I am trying to find a solution for this ode. My suggestion is that we can  rewrite the above equation as

$x^{2}(1+x^{2})y''+2xy'+A(1+2x^{2})y=-Ax^{4}y$

Then, the left side is a hypergeo polynomial. But i have no idea about the right side. How can i find the complete solution of this ode?

Comment: @Moo Thanks for your reply. I am trying to find an analytical solution bcz the numerical solution is not useful for me.

Comment: @Moo The point is that there are some special methods to have a solution for such quasi-solvable ode. Like Factorization method or Homotopy method and etc. Anyway, i wrote this question here, maybe other have a different method that help me for this ode.